# Is Tor supposed for daily day browsing? (youtube, news, stuff...)

Tags: help

Is Tor Browser supposed/meant for daily day browsing? (watching youtube, news, stuff...)

Answer (score 1):

Tor can be used for anything, may it be leaking secret documents or browsing YouTube. From my experience using Tor for everyday browsing is unnecessary because you can use a VPN (Virtual Private Network) which is faster than Tor. Also the No-script add on will block Youtube from playing unless specially configured. So, I don't think it necessary to use Tor for everyday because there are better solutions out there.

Comment: To add to this answer: Tor makes you anonymous, but if you use it as your default browser, you create patterns that are easy to track (allowed scripts, logged in accounts, etc)

Comment: It is a bad idea to use Tor only for "covert" activies. This creates patterns in your Tor usage with the outcomes of your Tor usage. It also signals to an observer that are doing something requiring high security. The more than you can use Tor for the less they will be able to infer about your Tor usage.